# Разница между функциями

Tags: c++

В чём разница между 3 функциями?

```
void main() {}
int main() {}
int main() {return 0;}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если речь о глобальной функции, с которой начинается любая программа на `C++`, то первый вариант не соответствует Стандарту, но может восприниматься как расширение, например в msvc. Вторая и третья функции эквивалентны, т.к. отсутствие явного `return 0;` в `main` допустимо Стандартом.

Answer (score 4):

Формально - без разницы. `main` это такая особая функция, которая все равно возвратит 0, даже если ей это не сказать - поскольку возвращает она это значение не вызывающей функции, а операционной системе.